# Dynamic Nash Bargaining Solution

Tags: game-theory, optimal-control, dynamic-programming, maximum-principle

**Static Game**

Let $i \in \{1, 2\}$ denote a player.
Each player can execute an action $a_i \in A_i$, where $A_i \subseteq \mathbb R$ denotes the set of feasible actions.
Given a pair of actions $a = (a_1, a_2) \in A = A_1 \times A_2$ each player derives a payoff defined by the function $u_i : A \to \mathbb R$.
Let $d = (d_1, d_2) \in \mathbb R^2$ denote a given outside option (threat-point).
The Nash Bargaining Solution $u(\overline a) = (u_1(\overline a), u_2(\overline a))$ is defined as the payoff that result from the following program
\begin{align}
&{\overline a} \in \arg\max_{a \in A}(u_1(a) - d_1) \cdot (u_2(a) - d_2)\\
\text{s.t.} \quad & u(a) \geq d 
\end{align}

**Dynamic Game**

Let $t \in T = \mathbb R_+$ denote time.
Now, each player chooses an action path $a_i : T \to A_i$.
Let $s : T \to S$ denote the state variable, where $S \subseteq \mathbb R$ denotes the state-space.
Assume that the state is governed by a stationary differential equation $f : S \times A \to S$ such that
\begin{align}
{\dot s}(t) = \frac{{\text d} s(t)}{{\text d} t} = f(s(t), a(t)).
\end{align}
Let $\mathcal A_i = \{\alpha_i : S \to A_i\}$ denote the set of feasible stationary Markovian feedback stratgies and $\mathcal A = \mathcal A_1 \times \mathcal A_2$ the joint strategy space.
The payoff function $u_i : S \times A \to \mathbb R$ now also depends on the state.
The (stationary) payoff functional $U_i : S \times \mathcal A \to \mathbb R$ is defined as
\begin{align}
U_i(s, \alpha) = \left[\int_{t}^{\infty}{e^{-\delta(\tau - t)} u_i(s(\tau), \alpha(s(\tau))){\text d} \tau} ~ \Bigg| ~ s = s(t)\right]
\end{align}
where $\delta > 0$ denotes the time-preference rate.
Let $d_i : S \to \mathbb R$ denote a state-dependend outside option.

For $s \in S$, the Dynamic Nash Bargaining Solution $U(s, \overline \alpha)$ is defined as the payoff that results from the following program
\begin{align}
&\overline \alpha \in \arg\max_{\alpha \in \mathcal A} (U_1(s, \alpha) - d_1(s)) \cdot (U_2(s, \alpha) - d_2(s))\\
\text{s.t.} \quad &\dot s = f(s, \alpha)\\
& U(s, \alpha) \geq d(s)
\end{align}

- Can something be said about solvability of this program?
- Is it possible to apply standard optimal control techniques (say, Maximum Principle or Dynamic Programming)?